# Problem to display an infopath form linked to an empty list

Tags: 2010, infopath, list-view, connected-web-parts

I'm working with sharepoint 2010. I have a list view filtered by the current user. Logically, if none of the items have the current user in its corresponding field, the list view is empty. An infopath has a connexion type "get form from" with this list. Unfortunately, when the list is empty, instead of an infopath form with blank fields, the following message is displayed : "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted or renamed by another user." Is it possible to change this message? display the infopath form with blank fields? or even better, switch to another view of the infopath form?
Thanks!

Comment: how did you set up the Connection in the InfoPath?

Comment: It's a "get form from" connection